# IIS 7.5 site user connects on one IP address but server side scripts need to AD authenticate on different range

Tags: asp.net, iis, forms-authentication

I've set up an IIS 7.5 web site on physical network card with the IP address 192.168.1.2 - of which the only thing connected is an unsecure Apple AirPort extreme.

Meanwhile, on the other physical LAN adapter, I have our Active Directory domain. My plan for the unsecured web site is for users to connect to it, the server side scripts run to authenticate the user's AD account by finding their way to the 10.x.y.z network, authenticate (or not) and present the authenticated web page to the user (still on the 192.168.1.2 range). The 192.168.1.x range has DHCP, a DNS with one entry "website" and NO default gateway.

All of that is working, except for the authentication.

Written is VB ASP.Net (and ripped straight from an MSDN article) I assume this is the line that needs to be syntactically correct:-

```
Dim adPath As String = "LDAP://DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=LOCAL" 'Path to your LDAP directory server
```

*Somehow* I need to get the scripts that run server side to authenticate (against AD) the user's credentials.

This is so users can self install our *secured* network configuration by connecting to, and authenticating through, an unsecured web site.

If the server side scripts run in the 192.168.1.x range, can they find their way to the 10.x.y.z range?

Thanks

Mark

Comment: You might get this question answered better over at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/). I've shun the IT hat for about a decade now, but if memory serves, its best/easier if you have an appliance that manages the _network_ routing/NATing/port forwarding for you...omg, I have flashbacks of the `DMZ` :) So a soft "yes" from me - if you configure your network properly...Hth...

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I could not have been more wrong about this issue. The reason it was not authenticating was due to an issue with IIS 7.5 running on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, the identity used  - 'Classic .NET AppPool' and that account's password expiry. *Normally* this does not cause an issue *unless* you try to use the account for AD membership lookups. This problem has been discussed elsewhere on StackOverflow.